# Boost Graph edges with indexes

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I am trying to define a graph with undirected edges from a set of pair(int,int) edges (where each int represents a vertex index). Each such edge has an index of its own.

The catch is that I want that the internal vertex index of the graph will be consistent with the original vertex indexes. I also like to be able to extract the original edge index from an edge descriptor.

From http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html (**Exterior Properties** section)  I understand that I should use the following graph type:

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, udirectedS, 
no_property, property<edge_index_t, std::size_t> > Graph;
```

Unfortunately there's no explanation on how to use edge_index_t property.

It's clear that I could just use a map(pair(int,int),int) but I'm looking for a more elegant boost oriented solution.

Thank you, 
Kiril

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use vectors to define collection of vertices there is one-to one correspondence between vertex indices and vertex descriptors. You just need to define you graph object as follows:

```
Graph g(N);
```

Where N is number of vertices. This allocates N vertices, each vertex descriptor is a number from 0 to N-1.

To get edge index from the edge descriptor you can use get function: 
`get(edge_index, g, edge_descriptor);`. The edge descriptor you can get from iterators returned by `adjacent_vertices(v, g)` function.

Hope it what you've meant.

Comment: Does `v` in `adjacent_vertices(v, g)` represent index of the vertex?

Comment: @Daniel yes, in this case it represents the vertex index